# How to go through a listview and get the position of a item in it WITHOUT click on it Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get the position of a item in the list view and use it in a if.

Now i am going through the listview using a for loop, and i want when i find the specfic Product Id equal to the Same Product (if clause), and when i find it i use that position to update my list

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapterItensDoCarrinho.getCount(); i++) {
    Log.d("ENTROU", "ENTROU");
    Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(lsvCarrinhoCompras.getId()));
    if (produtoSelecionado.getId() == adapterItensDoCarrinho.getItemId(i)) {
        Log.d("ENTROU 2", "ENTROU 2");
        int novaQte = itemDoCarrinho.getQtdeSelecionada();
        novaQte++;
        itemDoCarrinho.setNome(produtoSelecionado.getNome());
        itemDoCarrinho.setQtdeSelecionada(novaQte);
        itemDoCarrinho.setPrecoItemVenda(produtoSelecionado.getPrecoProduto());
        adapterItensDoCarrinho.updateItemCarrinho(lsvCarrinhoCompras.getId(), itemDoCarrinho);
        break;
    }
    else {
        itemDoCarrinho.setNome(produtoSelecionado.getNome());
        itemDoCarrinho.setQtdeSelecionada(qtdeProduto);
        itemDoCarrinho.setPrecoItemVenda(produtoSelecionado.getPrecoProduto());
        adapterItensDoCarrinho.addItemCarrinho(itemDoCarrinho);
    }
}
```

Hope you understand it!

Answer (score 2):

Your Adapter should be the one to handle this behavior. Write a public method in the Adapter class which allows you to pass in the selected product ID. Whenever the selected product ID changes in your Activity/Fragment/whatever, call the public method in the Adapter to update the product ID value. Then, in the `getView()` method of the Adapter, if the ID matches, perform whatever special behavior you want to have happen for the product with that ID.

Comment: But to update the name of the product, i need the position on the listview and to update the list in my adapter, have some way to do it?